Book reader with spaced repetition flashcards functionality
I am looking for a book reader application on iOS/Android that supports EPUB and PDF file formats. The reader should have a highlighting function that automatically creates spaced repetition flashcards using the highlighted information as answers. The questions should be generated automatically using AI.
Which application has such functionality? Do any eBook readers, such as Kobo or Boox, offer this feature?
P.S. I am aware of Kindle's flashcard functionality, but it only works for word translations and not for highlighted information. Kindle's iOS/Android application has too basic flashcards function.
